# How to make and submit a sitemap for a multilingual (translated) website (subdomains)?

Tags: seo, sitemap, multilingual, hreflang, multi-subdomains

I run a website that's been translated over Weglot to 5 languages, and now I have 5 different subdomains for `https://www.example.eu/`, like `https://it.example.eu/`, etc. First, I was worried will Google see it as duplicate content, but then I found I should use href lang on the page to tell Google it's a language variation or submit it in sitemap. But then I found here I can't submit one sitemap for different subdomains, that I have to make separate sitemaps for separate subdomains but they all have the same/translated content. In all this mess, what's the best way to tell Google to index those "separate sites" but also to link it somehow for Google to know it's not duplicate?